# Polyhedral conditions for quadratic inequalities in fixed dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inequalities, quadratic-forms

Denote $\mathcal T$ be set of $(T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4)\in\mathbb Z^4$ that satisfy
$$0<T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$$ 
conditions?

Define the level set $$M_{\gamma}(Q,\mathcal T)=\{(T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4)\in\mathcal T:Q(T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4)<\gamma \}$$ where $Q(w,x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z[w,x,y,z]$ is a quadratic form.

It is clear $0\leq |M_\gamma(Q,\mathcal T)|$ holds.

Fix a $0<\gamma_1<\gamma_1+1\leq\gamma_2$. If we restrict the set $\mathcal T$ to a smaller set $\mathcal T'$ by including linear conditions on $(T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4)$ then how many linear conditions should we add to guarantee $$|M_{\gamma_{_1}}(Q,\mathcal T')|<|M_{\gamma_{_{2}}}(Q,\mathcal T')|$$ before we can say $|M_{\gamma_{_1}}(Q,\mathcal T')|=|M_{\gamma_{_{2}}}(Q,\mathcal T')|$ holds no matter what linear conditions we pick?

Comment: Sorry, you ask the same in principal question for fourth time, deleting previous ones.

Comment: @PietroMajer Could you elaborate why this should play and how?

Comment: Thinking to the shape of a sublevel set $\{Q<-1\}$, of a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$, say in normal form, I would say that in order that the  intersection of $k$ half-spaces with $\{Q<-1\}$ contains finitely many lattice points, you need  the intersection to be bounded, and to do that it is necessary that $k$ be  larger than the negative index of inertia of $Q$ (assuming it is not zero)

Comment: @PietroMajer Thank you but how large? Here for fixed dimension quadratic form $k$ is fixed?

Comment: E.g. the worst case is $Q=-T_1^2-T_2^2-T^2_3-T_4^2$, so that  $\{Q<-1\}$ is the complement of the unit ball. To bound finitely many lattiece points of it, you need to intersect it with at least 5 half-spaces, whose intersection is a $4$-dimensional simplex.

Comment: @PietroMajer Could you please elaborate your ideas? It might help everyone if you have upper bound in special cases?

Comment: Or for  $Q=T_1^2+T_2^2-T^2_3-T_4^2$, you only need 3. Their intersection with the 2-dimensional negative eigenspace being  a triangle.

Comment: @PietroMajer 'only need' sounds like an upper bound. Why does it work?

Comment: I think it works because you can always choose k+1 half-spaces whose intersection with {Q<-1} is a bounded set, hence containing finitely many lattice points ( yet as many as you like ).

Comment: I assume that the trivial solution of just adding 2 incompatible linear conditions F>0 and -F>0, to make the intersection empty is not of interest to you. (btw it's not clear if you assume only $T_1$ positive, or all the $T_j$)

Comment: @PietroMajer does it answer the problem above?

Comment: I suggest that you edit and clarify the assumptions and the question.

Comment: @PietroMajer sorry what exactly is unclear and I will update?

Comment: OK now the question is a bit changed, but would you describe what you exactly mean by *"adding linear conditions"*? Does this operation depend on $\gamma$? But what is $\gamma$? :'(

Comment: @PietroMajer updated so it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by replacing  the quadratic form Q with a collection of zero-one binary variables and linear inequalities.  This answer is trying to keep with the spirit of earlier deleted questions, and shows how to impose conditions on quadratic forms using only linear constraints plus binary variable constraints.

I show in detail how to do this if all variables are binary (which is a standard technique in (mixed) integer linear programming), then outline the extension (which shows it can be done) to general (positive) integer variables.

Squares of binary variables are replaced by the unsquared variable.

For each mixed product term, $x_iy_i$ of binary variables, introduce a zero-one binary variables, b$_i$  Then the product $x_iy_i$ can be replaced by $b_i$, with the addition of linear inequalities:

$$b_i \le x_i$$
$$b_1 \le y_i$$
$$b_1 \ge x_i + y_i - 1$$

For the generalization to product terms (including squares of variables) consisting of integer, not necessarily binary, variables. Encode each variable in the product by its binary expansion. Then in the product, replace the variables with their binary expansions. This produces a sum of products of binary variables.  Each of these products can be replaced with an additional binary variable and accompanying inequalities, as shown above.

Now there is a system of linear inequalities and binary variables which encode the original quadratic form. You can then do what you want with the quadratic form, including subjecting it to inequalities.

There may be a lot of binary variables and linear inequalities, but it can be done.

Comment: sorry my problem is not binary and there is a reason I used four variables so increasing variables is pointless.

Comment: I showed how to do this for general integers, which covers your case. I started with binary to show in detail how to do that. The extension to general integer variables uses the binary solution as a building block. You never said that adding variables  isn't allowed, so I added variables ans linear constraints.

Comment: you increase the variable count from fixed dimension dont you see? it is rather pointless and what you show is a standard AND boolean trick. It does not even address the problem which is number theoretic. The problem is to control spurious points with polyhedral conditions in same dimension or else this problem would be in cstheory.